# Как передать код html из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Есть код, он из селекта отправляет текст в js, из js в php для обработки и из php обратно в js. Как мне вывести в form-control текст, полученный из php.

```
var str = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax(
{
   type: "POST",
   url: "check.php",
   data: str+"distance="+inputText,
   success: function(msg)
   {
      //тут нужно вывести из php текст '<option value="0">Москва1</option>'
      $(".form-control").prepend( $('<option value="0">Москва1</option>'));
   }
});
```

Если я напрямую без php сделаю

```
$(".form-control").prepend( $('<option value="0">Москва1</option>'));
```

То, option добавляется к селекту,
пробовал

```
$(".form-control").prepend(msg);
```

Селект пуст. В самом php делаю

```
echo '<option value="0">Москва1</option>';
```

Comment: попробуйте `$(".form-control").prepend( $(msg) );`

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте JSON для обмена данными между JS и PHP.
В JS формируйте объект который в PHP распарсите стандартной функцией.
Обработанные данные также верните из PHP в JSON. и потом вставьте их в нужные места.

В JS (отправка данных):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'check.php',
data: '{"str": str}', 
success: function(data) { 

  $(".form-control").prepend( $('<option value="0">'+ data.city +'</option>'));

},
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json'
});
```

а также можете воспользоваться сокращенной функцией

```
$.post( 'check.php', { 'string': 'str' }, function(data) { 
      $(".form-control").prepend( $('<option value="0">'+ data.city +'</option>'));
}, 'json');
```

В PHP для обработки JSON используйте [`json_decode($json)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), а потом, для отправки данных обратно, [`json_encode($array)`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).

В самом PHP прочитать переданное можно так

```
$string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'str', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Экзотический метод без сторонних библиотек

document.getElementById("script").src="http://ya.ru/file.php";

в file.php
echo "alert('lol');";

Если нужно, в src можно дописать параметры для get запроса